# nginx SNI not working as expected

Tags: nginx

I have been dealing with this for the past few days and it is driving me nuts.  I have nginx acting as a reverse proxy in front of apache. I have two vhosts each setup with their own ssl cert in nginx.  Here are the relevant sections of the nginx config (I think)

**VHOST1**

```
listen 443;

  server_name *.xxx.org xxx.org 64.58.248.26;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-ssl.access.log;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/xxx-ssl.error.log;

  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.org.pem;

  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:15m;

  ssl_session_timeout 15m;
```

**VHOST2**

```
listen 443;

  server_name *.yyy.org yyy.org;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/yyy-ssl.access.log;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/yyy-ssl.error.log;

  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/yyy.org.pem;

  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/yyy.key;

  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:15m;

  ssl_session_timeout 15m;
```

With this configuration I always get the right certificate for xxx.org when I visit it.  However when I go to yyy.org sometimes nginx uses the xxx.org certificate and sometimes it uses the right one (yyy.org).  I cant seem to find any rhyme or reason why it chooses to use the wrong cert when it does.  If I hit the apache servers directly rather than proxying through nginx all is working fins so I believe the problem lies with nginx somewhere.

I am on uBuntu 10.04.4 and SNI is enabled according to nginx -V.

Would the SSL_SESSION_CACHE being shared cause this behavior?
If I bypass nginx and go straight to Apache this works fine everytime

Comment: Ok, its not the SSL_SESSION_CACHE as I tried setting it to none and I am still having the same issues.

Comment: Are you doing something silly like using Internet Explorer on Windows XP?

Comment: The funny thing is I haven't even seen the error in IE.  Just chrome and FF

Comment: Oh, you forgot to mention what version of nginx you were using and where you got it from.